# TensorFlow: How does one check for bottlenecks in data input pipeline?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm currently using tf-slim to create and read tfrecord files into my models, and through this method there is an automatic tensorboard visualization available showing:

1. The tf.train.batch `batch/fraction_of_32_full` visualization, which is consistently near 0 value. I believe this should be dependent on how fast the dequeue operation gives the tf.train.batch FIFO queue its tensors.
2. The parallel reader `parallel_read/filenames/fraction_of_32_full` and `paralell_read/fraction_of_5394_full` visualizations, which are always at 1.0 value. I believe this op is what extracts the tensors from the tfrecords and put them into a queue ready for dequeuing.

My question is this: Is my dequeuing operation too slow and causing a bottleneck in my model evaluation?

Why is it that "fraction_of_32" appears although I'm using a batch size of 256? Also, is a queue fraction value of 1.0 the ideal case? Since it would mean the data is always ready for the GPU to work on.

If my dequeueing operation is too slow, how do I actually improve the dequeueing speed? I've checked the source code for tf-slim and it seems that the decoder is embedded within the function I'm using, and I'm not sure if there's an external way to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. If batch/fraction_of_32_full gets close to zero, it means that you are consuming data faster than you are producing it.

32 is the default size of the queue, regardless of your batch size. It is wise to set it at least as large as the batch size.

This is the relevant doc: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch

Setting `num_threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()`, and `capacity = batch_size` can help to keep the queue full.